# Best way to make scrollable UI in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, surfaceview

I'm trying to make scrollable fragment (horizontally and vertically). Project looks like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwjEi.png).
Of course this tree will be much bigger and it will be generated in runtime.

What is the best approach to achieve at least something similar? I'm thinking about SurfaceView and drawing everything with Canvas, however every other fragment in my application is using simple material elements, like this (not final) [home view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CAoJ.png). Is it bad practice to make game-like UI just for one fragment? Or maybe it's too much for my needs and standard libraries will be enough?

I'm asking about best approach (good practice and best user experience), not necessarily simplest solution, but answers raising this subject are also very welcome.

Comment: Your home view isn't actually Material, although that doesn't matter too much. Also, you ask if creating a custom tree View is too much for your needs, but we don't even know what your needs are.

Comment: I attached project UI for that fragment, I want to make it, that's my need